# Curl (*nix) upload file to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, curl, file-upload

I have an old redhat 8 box that I need to pragmatically send files to my webserver from. Disregarding the security issues with this, I've come up with the following way.

`curl -F file=@<filename> http://webhost/reciever.aspx`

The problem is, no matter what I try, the ASP.NET page is not accepting the file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of ASP.Net are you posting too?

Normally ASP.net will check to make sure the form was visited before processing the postback. This behaviour can be disabled with **enableViewStateMac**="false"  in the page declaration.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx